# Yehi H̱asdeikha before Ashrei Yoshevei

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mincha-afternoon-prayer

According to the Sefaradic Nusach, why do we sometimes see "*Ashrei yoshevei*" preceded by "*Yehi ẖasdeikha*"<sup>(1)</sup> and other times not?

---

<sup>(1)</sup>יְהִי חַסְדְּךָ יְהֹוָה עָלֵינוּ. כַּאֲשֶׁר יִחַלְנוּ לָךְ:‏

Answer (score 1):

From [Rav Goldberg](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=98293) I found the Yehi Chasdecha before the ashrei which is said after the Amida of Shacharit in Sepharadic nussach (some comunities say it even before ashrey starting Mincha). (in name of Shut Yaskil Avdi Orach Chayim 26, 6 I didn't find now the shut. but it seem's that the whole shut is [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx?title=%u05D9%u05E9%u05DB%u05D9%u05DC%20%u05E2%u05D1%u05D3%u05D9&auth=&ocr=&sort=0))

> הטעם שחלק מהסידורים הספרדים פותחים את המזמור "אשרי" , שאומרים בשחרית אחרי תפילת העמידה, בפסוק: "יהי חסדך ה' עלינו כאשר יחלנו לך" (תהלים לג, כב) משום שתחילתו באותיות יו"ד ה"א, והפסוק האחרון של המזמור "תהלה לדוד", שאומרים אחריו "ואנחנו נברך י-ה מעתה ועד עולם הללויה" (תהלים קטו, יח) – תחילתו בו"ו וסופו בה"א, אותיות שבצירופן מהוות את שם הוי"ה. ויש מוסיפים הפסוק בתחילה, הפסוק ה' הושיעה המלך יעננו ביום קראנו " ‏(שם כ, י) שגם פותח ביו"ד ה"א כפסוק הראשון.כל טוב ובשורות טובות ‏ ‏
>
> Certains Sepharadic Siddurs begin the Ashrey after Tefilat Shacharit by Yehi Chasdecha. This is a verse 22 of the psalm 33. The reason is that the first 2 letters of this verse are "Yod" and "He" and the last verse of Tehila ledavid (psalm 115, 18) says Vaanachnu nevarech Yah (yod, he) meata vead olam haleluyah (yod, he) as the first verse (begin with yod, he---ends with yod, he )

Note. Many communities begin ashrey of mincha with this verse,

Comment: can you continue with the last line i think there is some more to make it clear

Comment: @Yamin fixed///